# Count rows inside merged cells using Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am having some trouble figuring out how many rows are inside of a merged cell (Excel). For example, if cells "B4:B7" are merged, is there any way to use Python to determine that there are 4 rows composing that merged cell?

I am using openpyxl to access the spreadsheet but I am open to using other libraries (i.e. pandas) as long as it solves the problem. I know there is a function to check if a cell is merged but I am not sure if I can use that to figure out how many rows are in that merged cell. Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at the CellRange object? `mcr.max_row - mcr.min_row + 1`

Comment: Thank you for replying! I have not looked at the CellRange object before but I am reading about it now. Could you perhaps explain how to implement that line of code? What is the purpose of the mcr?

Comment: `mcr = MergedCellRange`